# Reading Encrypted File from Java

Tags: java, file, encryption

I have a .txt file in which I make the configuration for a certain system I'm building. 
Basically, after reading the file, I keep the variable values and set those values into what I need.
It would be nice if I could encrypt that information so that it wouldn't be readable if someone got access to that said file. The problem is that I really would not know how to decode it in my program. 
What is the most simple way to encode a text file? How do I decode in my program? 
A very important detail is that im building this app in JavaME which is limiting my set of tools to make this.

To summarize, I need to encrypt a file outsite the program and read it inside the program?

What is the easiest way to do so?

Thanks

Comment: Encode the string before you write it to file. And after reading the string from file -> decrypt it. Maybe you can use bouncycastle as encryption lib. I don't know if it works with JavaME.

Comment: Note: The file is written outside the program, the only thing I do in the program is read it, I'll take a look to "boucycastle" and see if I can use it! Thanks Benjamin!

Comment: Do you want do keep the data private (no read access) or do you want to prevent someone modifying the file?

Comment: Keep the data private! Do you think that if I change the permission to the file I would be able to solve the issue? Would it be usable on the program? Sorry if these questions sound basic but I'm kind of new to these matters.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to "encrypt a file outside the program"?

Read your plaintext file into your program, use an encryption algorithm (use a library, custom, etc.) to encrypt your text and them write that into a new file.

To decrypt, read encrypted file and run an inverse of your encryption function and do whatever you want with it in your program.

Comment: That could be an interesting solution, didn't really thought about it. Actually it's my first time dealing with encryption. I'll have to look for a library compatible with JavaME. Thanks a lot for your answer, orion!